# strokeColor and strokeWidth not working in androidx.cardview.widget.CardView android

Tags: android, material-design, android-cardview, androidx, material-components-android

Trying to make some border around `cardView` (`androidx.cardview.widget.CardView`)

Here's the code:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="273dp"
    android:layout_height="118dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"

    android:background="@drawable/fix_border" 
    app:strokeColor="#dedede"
    app:strokeWidth="3dp">

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Result:

[image: border not showing]

Also tried to use a custom shape as a background (`fix_border.xml`), doesn't work either.

`fix_border.xml`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#dedede" />
    <!--    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />-->
    <padding
        android:bottom="7dp"
        android:left="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:top="7dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) and the `MaterialCardView` which extends the `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView`.
Something like:

```
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        app:strokeColor="@color/primaryDarkColor"
        app:strokeWidth="3dp"
        ../>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to give a drawable background to a `CardView` (reference: [v7 cardview library issues](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37007602)), you can give it a `app:cardBackgroundColor` though, but if you need the stroke, you can add a layout inside it and add the drawable background with the stoke to that and it works. So, something like:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="273dp"
    android:layout_height="118dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">
    <!-- Any layout type here -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/fix_border">
        <!-- Build your layout, with a background stroke! -->
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: what about ```strokeColor``` and ```strokeWidth``` aren't those supposed to work?

Comment: `strokeColor` and `strokeWidth` only work with `MaterialCardView`. See here: https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-card-view/